# How to pass an async variable to option in Vue Plugin (VueGoogleMaps)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Before I use package 'vue2-google-maps' in my app like that

```
// app.js 

import apiKey from './apiKeyGoogleMap';
import * as VueGoogleMaps from "vue2-google-maps";

Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
  load: {
    key: apiKey, //google map api key, load from apiKeyGoogleMap.js
    libraries: "places"
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  i18n,
  template: '<app/>',
  // Register App Component
  components: {
    app: App,
    ...
  }
});

// apiKeyGoogleMap.js
const apiKeyGoogleMap = '';
export default apiKeyGoogleMap;
```

And now, How I can load variable `apiKey` from an API instead load from apiKeyGoogleMap.js ?

```
// app.js
import * as VueGoogleMaps from "vue2-google-maps";
Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
  load: {
    key: apiKey, // I want to load this variable from API 
    libraries: "places"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can defer adding the plugin until your data has been loaded but then you should also defer creating the root Vue instance.

For example

```js
import * as VueGoogleMaps from "vue2-google-maps";

fetch("/api")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
      load: {
        key: data.apiKey,
        libraries: "places"
      }
    })

    new Vue({
      // router, store, render, etc
    }).$mount("#app")
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as Phil's answer but using a async/await function.
(I'm slow, but since I got this far, I might as well post it.)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import axios from 'axios' // Or fetch or similar.
import * as VueGoogleMaps from "vue2-google-maps";

async function run () {

  // This placeholder api does not have an apiKey of course.
  const apiUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
  const apiResponse = await axios.get(apiUrl)
  const { apiKey } = apiResponse.data 

  Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
    load: {
      key: apiKey,
      libraries: "places"
    }
  })

  new Vue({
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount('#app')
}

run()
```

If you don't want to wait for the request before you mount your app, then you can do the same inside a component and remove Vue.use(), which is only there to make the plugin global. (for example: https://dev.to/terrierscript/example-for-google-map-with-vuejs-without-vue-library--3gf5)